# Rails Ransack search in partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ransack

Here's more of a "can it be done" question, so not including any code unless it's necessary. Basically, I started using Ransack and got it working with the basic functionalities in my users#search action. Now, I want to include this as a partial into a different page, so that when I search/filter, it only updates the partial results and not the rest of the page. I've included a partial with a Ransack search form and if I search, it redirects to a new page (the users/search page created originally). So, if I use `search_form_for`, Ransack instantly routes to a new path (I can manipulate this via `url`). Can I change this behavior to reload a partial? I attempted using jQuery `get`, but the underlying issue is I can't seem to reload just the partial via the response. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?